# How to restrict php function to use specific amount of RAM?

Tags: php, memory

Is there any way to restrict php function to use specific amount of computer RAM.
There are different RAM memory on local and server . I want to test it on local with only 1 GB Ram is this possible here is function

```
    public function handle()
    {
       

            $pdfMerger = new  PdfMerger();

            $bulk_pdf = public_path('bulk-pdf-consignment/manifest' . $this->manifest_id . '_.pdf');
            $allFilesPath = public_path('bulk-pdf-consignment/manifest_' . $this->manifest_id);

            if (File::exists($bulk_pdf)) {
                $pdfMerger->addPDF($bulk_pdf, 'all');
            }
            $filesInFolder = collect(File::files($allFilesPath))->sortBy(function ($file) {
                return $file->getCTime();
            });

            $arr = [];
            $filesCount = 0;
            $x = '';
            foreach ($filesInFolder as $path) {
                $file = pathinfo($path);
                $finalPath = $file['dirname'] . '/' . $file['basename'];

                $added =  $pdfMerger->addPDF($finalPath, 'all');
                if ($added) {
                    array_push($arr, $finalPath);
                }
                $filesCount++;
                echo "real: ".(memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024/1024)." MiB\n\n";
                $x .= str_repeat(' ', 1024*25); //store 25kb more to string
            }

            $merged =  $pdfMerger->merge("file", $bulk_pdf);


            if ($merged) {
                $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url('bulk_pdf_consignments/manifest' . $this->manifest_id . '_.pdf', fopen($bulk_pdf, 'r+'));

           
                Notification_Helper::sendNotification($this->user_id, 'Download Bulk Print Label PDF'.$filesCount, $url,$this->user_type);
            
                if ($this->user_type == 'staff') {
                    $user = Staff::find($this->user_id);
                }
                    if ($this->user_type == 'customer') {
                        $user = Contact::find($this->user_id);
                    }
                    sendEmail($user->email, 'Manifest Consignment Labels PDF ', $url, $attachment = null);
                    // File::delete($bulk_pdf);
                    // File::deleteDirectory($allFilesPath);
                    // foreach ($arr as $file) {
                        File::delete($finalPath);
                    // }
                }
            }
```

I want to test it as i am on live server

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to set the php memory_limit, add the following line to the top of your script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1G');
```

https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/

Comment: this function set RAM allocation?

Comment: That is how I understand it

Comment: Ok what will happen if function required 50 Mb ram and we are assigning it only 20 Mb Ram . it will fail?

Comment: The article I provided a link for explains this